# Expressing employee availability as a bitwise operation

Tags: c#, enums, bitwise-operators

I am building a scheduling app for my employees and I want to store availability for my employees for every day of the week, Sunday through Saturday. Every employee has an option for selecting { Available, Not Available, 1stHalf, 2ndHalf } for their availability each day. I think an enum could work to store all 7 days, and a bitwise operation could work for determining which type of availability the employee has for that day. Is this possible?

Comment: Enum with `Flags` attribute (Available = 1stHalf | 2ndHalf). enum identifiers can not begin with a number though.

Comment: There's already a `DayOfWeek` enum available. Why not create an enum for the Availablility, though? It would certainly improve readability

Comment: 4 states * 7 days, = 28 values, so yes that should work.  I.E. It is possible.

Comment: It's probably easier to work with one enum value per day. Saves you from typing a bit of code...I'd imagine. No need to overengineer unless you have a reason to do so

Comment: I would store the `StartTime` and `EndTime` instead. It will be more flexible. You can still show *First Half* to your employees during selection but when you store it, conver it to what first half means-for example, 09:00 to 13:00. If you decide to have night shifts or overtime etc, all you will need is to change the UI and the rest will work.

Comment: I agree with @CodingYoshi. If you're building a scheduling app, try to build it to be as flexible as possible. Scheduling can be a very tricky and things can change pretty quickly. Tying yourself down to `All Day / First Half / Second Half / None` does not give you the flexibility you will probably need down the road.

Comment: If you use *First Half* approach, you will have if conditions everywhere in the application. For example, if you want to know total hours, you will have `if half then do this else if all day do this and so on`

Comment: @RufusL I am limited by my workplace to those four options. That is, we use an app to gather availability that only returns those four options.

Comment: So what specifically is the input? Is it just those four options? Where does the DayOfWeek come into play? How are you integrating with the other app (how are you consuming the input)?

Comment: @RufusL The other app is a Google Sheet that employees fill out. For every day of the week, they select from a drop-down menu one of the four options I've mentioned. I manage the sheet, so theoretically I could add whatever options I want, but my workplace prohibits me from adding more options because there are people who will begin specifying odd availability constraints and we want to avoid that. I convert the sheet to a CSV file and parse it using a library called FileHelpers into object representations of those CSV files.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Sounds like a fun project.

Comment: @RufusL It's fun for sure. I hope it will save my shop hundreds of man-hours per year. Our current system involves manually parsing email replies from 60 employees for 7 days of availability per employee, then manually inputting their avail into an Access DB that gets corrupted every few weeks due to network latency.

Comment: @DennisKuypers There is only one enum value per day, but there are four options to choose from. Does that make sense?

Comment: @CodingYoshi I agree. The problem of scheduling in my workplace, though, is always based on those four values. We don't operate on hourly availability when we schedule people. We only consider one of those four values. The shift times often change, but the employees know those times and label their availability using one of the four values for each day.

Comment: @CodingYoshi I am ultimately using the availability values for each employee to set constraints for a Constraint Programming solver. I will use the avail values to determine which employees are avail for the first shift and second shift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah it should be possible you can do something like this

```
public class Schedule
{
    private int schedule;

    public Schedule(Availability sunday, Availability monday, Availability tuesday, Availability wednesday, Availability thursday, Availability friday, Availability saturday)
    {
        this.schedule = sunday | monday << 2 | tuesday << 4 | wednesday << 6 | thursday << 8 | friday << 10 | saturday << 12;
    }

    public Availability Sunday
    {
        get
        {
            return (this.schedule & 3);
        }
    }

    public Availability Monday
    {
        get
        {
            return (this.schedule >> 2) & 3;
        }
    }

    public Availability Tuesday
    {
        get
        {
            return (this.schedule >> 4) & 3;
        }
    }

    public Availability Wednesday
    {
        get
        {
            return (this.schedule >> 6) & 3;
        }
    }

}

public enum Availability
{
    Available = 0,

    NotAvailable = 1,

    FirstHalf = 2,

    SecondHalf = 3
}
```

I stopped at Wednesday but hopefully you can see the pattern used. You can use two bits to represent each day. The number 3 is "11" in binary. This is bitshifted into the correct location for the desired day, then we use bitwise and to get the set bits for that day. After we shift the bits we grabbed to the right.

Comment: No need to shift twice, just shift before masking.  e.g. `return (schedule >> 4) & 3;`

Comment: If I add a 5th option for an avail type, then I'd require 3 bits. That means I couldn't store the schedule as an int since there would 7*6 bits required. Sure, I could use a long....but what if I needed, say, 200 bits for future options? How would you handle that?

Comment: 3 bits would only require 7*3 bits. If you really needed more room in the future don't try to fit the whole schedule into one variable. Just assign each enum to its own individual field in the constructor, so each property just returns the enum value assigned to it. You wouldn't need to do any bitmasking operations this way. You won't ever need more than 7 int fields since an enum can only hold 32 bits worth of values and there's only seven days in the week.